# About merging of questions

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266771/why-does-the-clock-work-slowly-at-higher-speed) of mine merged with [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241772/what-is-time-dilation-really) while the questions were pretty different with each other. And [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241772/what-is-time-dilation-really/266773#266773) of Gennaro Tedesco (before is edited by me, even after that!) is completely meaningless.

Why **must** those questions be merged?

---

I could explain clearly why those questions were merged if the moderator who merged the questions, wasn't deleting comments related to that answer of Gennaro Tedesco. But now, I cannot.

If you have access to deleted comments and you can recover them, please help for clarification of this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This represents a misstep on my part, but it is not easily reversed. (Indeed, I don't know if it can be reversed.)

At the time I was concerned that there was a single answer to a closed question that uses slightly unusual language that—in my opinion—might mislead the reader not withstanding that it isn't "wrong" *per se*. I felt that by putting it in the context of other good answers it would be less likely to mislead, but overlook the fundamentally different phrase of the (same underlying) question.

Comment: The [PostHistory table](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) in SEDE has a PostHistoryType of Question Unmerged (Id=22), so it should be possible, but maybe only by a team member. Otherwise, it might be better to just delete both question and answer and start again.